# How to get admin using getting the contact id and accountId

Tags: apex

```
User u = [SELECT Id,ContactId,Contact.AccountId FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

id conid=uContactId;
id acid=u.Contact.AccountId;
```

this are possible  or not, please anybody help me

Answer (score 2):

Accountid and contactid are populated if you run this as a community user /portal users .For admin Users those value are null